# Extract common strings (comma separated) in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

Suppose I have a table in Redshift:
Table X

```
Col1      Col2
C,B,A     B
```

I want to return a third column Col3 with the common output of Col1 and Col2. Strings are not necessarily in order. Desired output:

```
Col1      Col2    Col3
C,B,A     B       B
```

How can I do this in SQL Redshift?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something of this sought, as I dont have access to Redshift at the moment. And considering the Redshift is similar to Postgres. Tried the below to be able to get the needed result.

```sql
CREATE TABLE TEST (
Col1 VARCHAR(500),
Col2 VARCHAR(500)
);


INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('A,B,C', 'B');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('Cat,Dog,Hen', 'Hen');
```

```sql
SELECT *, 
strpos(col1, col2) AS value, 
length(col2) as len,
substr(col1, strpos(col1, col2), length(col2)) as sub,
regexp_matches(col1, col2) as matc --use REGEXP_SUBSTR for Redshift instead
FROM 
Test;
```

> Note : Please be sure to replace the `regexp_matches` with `REGEXP_SUBSTR`

| col1 | col2 | value | len | sub | matc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A,B,C | B | 3 | 1 | B | ['B'] |
| Cat,Dog,Hen | Hen | 9 | 3 | Hen | ['Hen'] |

Hope this helps